# SharedPreference is not reading the values of xml data

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to share data from **Context Activity** to **Fragment Activity** through `SharedPreferences`

I can see the data available in `XML` file but when I call the data it show null `""`

Here is the sample how I saved the data:

```
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences("USER_LOCATION",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences trial= getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TRIAL1",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPreferences.edit();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor2= trial.edit();

        editor.putString("ADDRESS",userAddress);
        editor.putString("LATITUDE",String.valueOf(latitude));
        editor.putString("LONGITUDE",String.valueOf(longitude));
        editor.putString("country",Country);
        editor.putString("state",State);
        editor.putString("city",City);
        editor.apply();

        editor2.putString("ADDRESS",userAddress);
        editor2.putString("LATITUDE",String.valueOf(latitude));
        editor2.putString("LONGITUDE",String.valueOf(longitude));
        editor2.putString("country",Country);
        editor2.putString("state",State);
        editor2.putString("city",City);
        editor2.commit();
```

And here is how I tried to retrieve the data:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref= v.getContext().getSharedPreferences("USER_LOCATION", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences trial= getContext().getSharedPreferences("TRIAL1",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String h=sharedPref.getString("latitude","");
    String hi=sharedPref.getString("longitude","");
    String h2=sharedPref.getString("COUNTRY","");
    String h3=sharedPref.getString("STATE","");
    String h4=sharedPref.getString("CITY","");
    System.out.println(h+ hi+ h2+ h3+ h4);

    String h1=trial.getString("latitude","");
    String hi1=trial.getString("longitude","");
    String h21=trial.getString("COUNTRY","");
    String h31=trial.getString("STATE","");
    String h41=trial.getString("CITY","");
    System.out.println(h1+ hi1+ h21+ h31+ h41);
```

I have used two sharedPreference with different method one with `Apply` & other with `Commit` however either one is not showing any values. It's a simple error and which I am not able to figure it out.

Here is the XML data:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<string name="country">India</string>
<string name="city">Diphu</string>
<string name="ADDRESS">Pilongri Bhavan, Vaikang Road, Rongkhelan, Diphu, Assam 782460, India</string>
<string name="LONGITUDE">93.44214149999999</string>
<string name="state">Assam</string>
<string name="LATITUDE">25.8595708</string>
</map>
```

Can anyone please let me know or explain me what I am doing wrong, I have also check the related **issue** but none were related with **why SharedPreference is not showing the data in Fragment which I stored in Activity.**

Comment: Could it be that u are getting key in diferent case(lower case and upper case) that you set, can u try put all in same case level?

Comment: `putString("LATITUDE"` AND `getString("latitude"` do not match.

Comment: Hahhah.. Thank you.. @blackapps it was a simple seeing issue. My bad. The key were wrong. Thank you

Comment: You should thank Rui Alves too. He told you first.

Comment: @RuiAlves Thank you too.

Comment: One Thing is that I am still not able to get the values of the String The "COUNTRY", "STATE", "CITY". it is still showing `" "`

Comment: I guess it should work now I have change the DATA in XML file

Comment: Its working now.